# Capture Mouse Position

Tags: c++, winapi

This is a Win32 program, and I Write a CaptureMousePosition function to capture the mouse's position.[image: This is CaptureMousePosition function.]

and I call the function in WM_MOUSEMOVE message.[image: This is where I call the function.]

Then I run the program.when my mouse moves on the red point, it is (126,112).There is no problem here.[image: run the program.]

But when my mouse moves on the blue point,it becomes (960,940).How can it happen,I don't understand, why the red point is (126,112),but the blue point is (960,940).the blue point should be ( < 126, < 112).how to fix it.[image]

Comment: I think you have some problems with your formatting or didn't paste things correctly

Comment: Did you take into account that `X == 0, Y == 0` at the top left of the screen?

Comment: Note also that "capturing the mouse" has a specific technical meaning which I don't think is how you are using it here.

Comment: I fix the problems, Now you can review the question.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of source code. Just post the source code as text. That way it is searchable. Also, you didn't say where `hWnd` and `lParam` came from, or how the red and blue dots are created. (Are they child windows?) You also didn't say what you get when you put the mouse halfway between the two dots, or when you move the mouse slowly between the two dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for `WM_MOUSEMOVE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645616%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) clearly states:

> Use the following code to obtain the horizontal and vertical position:
>
> ```
> xPos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam); 
> yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
> ```
>
> As noted above, the x-coordinate is in the low-order short of the return value; the y-coordinate is in the high-order short (both represent signed values because they can take negative values on systems with multiple monitors). If the return value is assigned to a variable, you can use the MAKEPOINTS macro to obtain a POINTS structure from the return value. You can also use the GET_X_LPARAM or GET_Y_LPARAM macro to extract the x- or y-coordinate.
>
> **Important** Do not use the LOWORD or HIWORD macros to extract the x- and y- coordinates of the cursor position because these macros return incorrect results on systems with multiple monitors. Systems with multiple monitors can have negative x- and y- coordinates, and LOWORD and HIWORD treat the coordinates as unsigned quantities.

Change this:

```
short nX;
nX = (short)LOWORD(lParam);
short nY;
nY = (short)HIWORD(lParam);
```

To this:

```
short nX;
nX = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam); 
short nY;
nY = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
```

Or this:

```
POINTS pt;
pt = MAKEPOINTS(lParam);

short nX;
nX = pt.x; 
short nY;
nY = pt.y;
```

**Update:** something else to note from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645616%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Posted to a window when the cursor moves. If the mouse is not captured, the message is posted to the window that contains the cursor. Otherwise, the message is posted to the window that has captured the mouse.

That means if the mouse has been captured via `SetCapture()`, the reported coordinates will be relative to the window that is doing the capturing, not the window that the mouse is actually moving over.

Comment: sorry，it doesn't work,I changed my code,but it still work like before.

Comment: Then that is simply how Windows is actually reporting the coordinates. Which window is your `WM_MOUSEMOVE` handler actually attached to? The red dot in your screenshot is NOT located at 126x112 of the client area it is being drawn on, it is closer to 116x116 instead. 126x112 would make sense only if the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message were being reported relative to the top-left corner of the main window, not the top-left corner of any client area inside of the window. `WM_MOUSEMOVE` is supposed to report coordinates that are relative to the client area of the window receiving the message.

Comment: That suggests to me that your main window has captured the mouse, even though it is moving over a child window.

Comment: sorry, I make a fool mistake, in fact, the blue dot is (96,94) ,not (960,940), it shows that because the length of textout function, and your answer is very useful for me ,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

Everything is just fine. The coordinates of the blue dot are `X = 96` and `Y = 94`. You are seeing `X = 960` because you are not erasing the 0 left over from `X = 100`. You would have noticed that the values are just fine if you had used a debugger to step through the code.

Answer (score 1):

Without showing your code, is hard to answer, but I guess, that problem is in Screen vs. Client coordinates.

Comment: sorry,I have no reputation to post images, but I don't know why it can post now, Anyway ,I'll appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: You posted the images just fine, you simply did not link to them correctly.